# Lucene search for ecommerce - order products in each category

Tags: search, solr, lucene, e-commerce, faceted-search

I am using **Lucene** for indexing/searching product catalog for an ecommerce application.

A product can be mapped to any number of categories.

We have a requirement to maintain a default sort order for products listing in each category. So, a product might have a different order-index for each mapped category.

When searching for product listing in a category, how to sort mapped products with default sort order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this by having a separate field for each sorting order, for example `category_motherboards_sort` with the index value of that document. The only issue here is that you'll have to be careful about the number of total fields you sort by, as you may get a very large FieldCache after a while - but exactly how that will work will depend on which version of Lucene you're using. Using DocValues should mitigate most of that cost.

If that's still an issue, you can usually solve it by retrieving all the documents for the category, then do the sort in your application layer instead. This works great for very sparse fields, where the field is only present in a low percentage of the total number of documents.

I'd try the first option first and profile the memory usage, before implementing the other option if necessary.